# Is this proof correct and rigorous? (Chapter 3, exercise 21 from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

The exercise states:

If $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of closed nonempty and bounded sets in a *complete* metric space $X$, if $E_n \supseteq E_{n+1}$, and if $$  \lim_{x \to \infty} \textrm{diam } E_n =0 $$ then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$ consists of exactly one point.

**Proof:**

Suppose that the intersection contains more than one point then by the inclusion relation, $E_n \supseteq E_{n+1}$, these points are in the entire sequence $\{E_n\}$. Hence $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \textrm{diam } E_n > 0 $. A contradiction, so there is at most one point in the intersection.

Now let us suppose that the intersection is empty. Thus $\big( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n} \big)^c=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}^{c}=X $. $E_n \supseteq E_{n+1}$ implies that $E_n^c \subseteq E_{n+1}^c$ $\forall N \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Because of the inclusion relation of the complements and the fact that the union of the sequence of complements must equal $X$ we say $\forall p \in X$ $ \exists K\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \in E_k^c$ $\forall k \geq K$ **(1)**. Define $S=\{K | \textbf{(1)} \textrm{ is satisfied, } p \in X\}$ and let $T=\sup S$. Hence $E_T^c=X$ and $E_T=\emptyset$, a contradiction. Thus $\exists p \in X \textrm{ such that } p \notin E_k^c \textrm{  } \forall k$ and thus $p \in E_k \forall k$.  Therefore the desired intersection is non empty and by the initial argument consists of exactly one point. $\square$

**Question** This chapter and indeed the exercise previous regards Cauchy sequences.  This combined with the fact that it is italicized that $X$ is a *complete* metric space makes me think like I should have used some property of Cauchy sequences. Alas, my primary question is: Is this proof correct and rigorous?

Comment: Your definition of $S$ does not make sense to me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I was trying to associate with each p in X the first K for which it first enters $E_n^c$.  Then the sup of all these values gives the first $E_n^c$ that contains every element of X which gives the contradiction that $E_n$ is empty.

Comment: Your argument fails because $\sup S$ can be $\infty$. Notice that you never use the fact that the space is complete. You would have to use Baire's theorem